# PHP MYSQL - Mutliple Queries and Outputs

Tags: php, mysql

I really appreciate any feedback and time you have for me.

I'm working on a PHP Page that queries a database with1 table and seem to be stuck. SQL is not my strong suit, so I seek some assistance. I'm working in PHP with MYSQL attached.

**Database**

I have a tables "Product" that contains:

```
1ID, 2Product Description, 3Price, 4Category, 5Size, 6Price-Category
```

I'd like to run a query to identify which products match by Size (exact match) and Price-Catgory (equal or higher). Therefore I thought about the following process:

```
A - run queries to identify different products by Category (one for Category A, one for Category B)
B - compare query A and B by Size and Price-Category
C - Display Results by ID for Category A
```

I would like to output the result per ID of my Query A Product :

```
1ID|2Product Description|3Price|4Category|5Size|6Price-Category|7Query B Details
1   Product              100    Cat       100   1               ID, Product. etc.
                                                                ID, Product. etc.
                                                                ID, Product. etc.

2   Product              200    Cat       100   2               ID, Product. etc.
                                                                ID, Product. etc.
                                                                ID, Product. etc.
```

Any ideas on how I could build this?

Thanks in advance!

Code I tried so far (I currently try to get them from two tables, but originnaly they were in one!!!!)

```
$query = "SELECT betten.m3, betten.Shortcode, betten.CodePDT, betten.PVCons, betten.CAT, betten.size1, betten.size2, betten.m3, betten.SIZE, betten.PRICERANGE, som.CodePDT2, som.Shortcode2, som.PRICECLASS, som.PVCons2, som.CAT2, som.size1a, som.size2a, som.m3a, som.SIZETWO FROM betten LEFT JOIN som ON betten.m3 = som.m3a ORDER BY CodePDT ";  
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        // Print out the contents of each row into a table 
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr><td>";
            echo $row['CodePDT']. "</td><td>".$row['Shortcode']. "</td><td>". $row['PVCons']."</td><td>". $row['CAT']. "</td><td>". $row['SIZE']. "</td><td>". $row['m3']."</td><td>". $row['PRICERANGE']. "</td><td>". $row['CodePDT2']. "</td><td>". $row['Shortcode2']. "</td><td>". $row['PVCons2']. "</td><td>". $row['CAT2']. "</td><td>". $row['SIZETWO']. "</td><td>". $row['m3a']. "</td><td>". $row['PRICECLASS']. "</td><td>";
            echo "</td></tr>";
        }
```

UPDATE:

This works, excepts the GROUP_CONT. Without, I get the results, but line by line. With GROUP_CONT I get an error "check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP_CONCAT(som.S...."

```
SELECT `betten`.*, `som`.*
FROM betten
    LEFT JOIN som ON betten.m3 = som.m3a    
    WHERE SIZE LIKE SIZETWO    
GROUP_CONCAT(som.Shortcode2) AS Dude
    GROUP BY betten.CodePDT    
    ORDER BY CodePDT ASC
```

Comment: yes plese show what u tried...  may be we will guide you....

Comment: @Mian_Khurram_Ijaz: "plz" don't use chat language on SO. Please paste some code.

Answer (score 0):

achieved through:

```
$query = ("SELECT
    r.rangename as rRangename,  /* Get Ranges from Rangetable */
    r.rangevalue as rRangevalue,
    m.name as mName, /* Get Fields from main Products */
    m.Code as mCode,
    m.Range as mRange,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(f.productcode ORDER BY f.index_id ASC SEPARATOR ','),',',3) as fCodes, /* Get Fields from Cross Selling and list them seperatly */
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(f.name ORDER BY f.index_id ASC SEPARATOR ','),',',3) as fNames,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(f.range ORDER BY f.index_id ASC SEPARATOR ','),',',3) as fRanges

FROM
    crossproducts f
JOIN /* Match main products with cross via m3 */
    mainproduct m
ON
    m.m3 = f.m3 
JOIN /* Match ranges and assign values for cross */
    ranges r
ON
    r.rangename = f.range
JOIN /* Match ranges and assign values for main */
    ranges s
ON
    s.rangename = m.Range
WHERE /* Only get Items that are equal or higher price range */
    r.rangevalue - s.rangevalue > -1

GROUP BY /* And finally group them by main Product Code */
    m.Code;");
```